# TypeScript: Extend props in React component conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to extend my component props conditionally depending on if a particular prop is passed.

My aim is to extend props by attributes of an `anchor` if a `href` prop is passed, and extend by attributes of a `button` if not.

Is this even possible?

Here's my attempt:[image]

Comment: Please don't post images please. Use the code formatting features of SO instead.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the pro tip

Comment: you can cast the component itself `<Button<Anchor> ...></Button>` and then update the definition `export const Button<T> = (p: Props<T>)`. The type definition would just extend then `type Props<T> = {...} & T`

Comment: Thanks John, good idea. I wonder if there is any way for this to work conditionally in the component itself without explicit casting

Comment: That would look something like this. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-3c07h

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just define properties as union type and use typeguard?
Something like this:

```js
type ButtonProps = { onClick: () => {} }
type LinkProps = { href: string }

type BaseProps = {
    spinner?: boolean
}

type Props = BaseProps & (ButtonProps | LinkProps)

export const Button = (props: Props) => {
    if ('href' in props) {
        // Link
    } else {
        // Button
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Aleksey but im seeing incompatible types now? How would i get around this: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-cohen-27cpw

Comment: @Samuel you [**should be able to have the correct type inference**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApQPYAOGyA3gFDKXKQAeYAXMhmFKAOZkC+ZoksiKAIIgEACzxRchYuSrJRUCDEbNWIDnID6YOFDYQGTFuy49w0eEjQBXMGDwgpRUhSoOAwgBtgCANYAKCEY4EABPAEpGADc8YAATUzIwUIIUJ2IAXjRMHHxnADJkf1Rbe0c84gAfZGExCXTwsjIEB2YbOwdkLP8CCsYGroA+FzlgGCKAcgUlCeRQZF7pcJG5KhaQNtAYaEU4pwAVFIhBDFrxKC6FiuQAehvkdc2Qbahdg6PGdCx05EKz+oqrlWD1aYGQ2l0+jBWUWRAAdBC9AZbvcQHhkDsJBggchOBjPFgVsDHmCtjsIHs8odUicSh0QJdYcQ7iCNqTnuTKYRqccMHSyp8cj9CvyHOkcXISQ8AEaMipwjzePwo5BojGvLE47icIA)